# Expanded widget not taking entire width or height

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I was learning about Expanded widget in Flutter.
What I understand is that Expanded widget takes entire width/height depending or `Row` / `Column`.

So,this is the code I used for `Row`:

```
class DicePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: Image(
            image: AssetImage('images/dice1.png'),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

And this is the output:

[image: https://imgur.com/5o8GQZ1]

It takes up the entire width of the screen and that's fine.

But,for `Column` this is what I used:

```
class DicePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: Image(
            image: AssetImage('images/dice1.png'),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

And the output is:

[image: https://imgur.com/dMs5UpG]

Why entire height is not taken by image here?

Answer (score 0):

I think that your image dimension are close to 1:1 so expanded widget expands it as much as the image allows. Try this to stretch the image:

```
child: Image(
            image: AssetImage('images/dice1.png'),
            fit: BoxFit.fill,
          ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **flex** property in Expanded Widget

```
Expanded(
    flex: 0,
),
```